# ember-data - record not found (404)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How are people handling 404 errors from ember-data?

At the moment, the rest-adapter handles errors in this way:

```
  didError: function(store, type, record, xhr) {
    if (xhr.status === 422) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      store.recordWasInvalid(record, data['errors']);
    } else {
      store.recordWasError(record);
    }
  },
```

I can tell if a model is invalid when trying to save it but I cannot tell if the record was not found when doing a find or findById.

How are people handling 404 errors?

Answer (score 0):

What i did was having 404 page in server which actually just have JSON string mentioning the error. And handle them in Ember. There may be better ways but this very easy and wont waste much of your time.

Eg:

```
[{"msg":"Data Not Found"}]
```

in FindAll or Find methods of Adapter you have like this

```
DS.Adapter.create({
    find: function(store, type, id) {
        var url = type.url;
        url = url.fmt(id);

        jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            // data is a Hash of key/value pairs. If your server returns a
            // root, simply do something like:
            // store.load(type, id, data.person)
            if(data.msg!=="Data Not Found")
                store.load(type, id, data);
        });
    }
});
```